# table elements acts different with align="center" vs css text-align: center;

Tags: html, css

I've got table elements within a table. The parent table has a width of 100% and the child table has a width of 300px. I want the child to be centered, so I tried with css to set it with text-align: center;. (https://jsfiddle.net/wrzo7LLb/1/)

```
<table class="body">
<tr>
  <td class="align center"> <!-- CSS text-align: center; -->
    <table class="wrapper">
     <tr>
       <td>
         some text
       </td>
     </tr>
    </table>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

But that doesn't work. And then I tried it with align="center" and that did work. (https://jsfiddle.net/wrzo7LLb/)

```
<table class="body">
<tr>
  <td align="center"> <!-- align="center" -->
    <table class="wrapper">
     <tr>
       <td>
         some text
       </td>
     </tr>
    </table>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Could someone explain to me why `align="center"` works, but `text-align: center;` doesn't?

*I know I can set `margin: 0 auto;`, but that doesn't explain why `align="center"` works and the other doesn't.*

Comment: Technically text-align should only be used to align non-block level elements, of which a table is not, regardless of if it works or not. The align property on a table doesnt refer to text but to the position of the table relative to its parent. I know youre asking why one works and not the other, just commenting on the semantics of the CSS use.

Comment: Thank you! I think that this would explain it. If you can put it up as an answer I will accept it as the correct answer.

Comment: Align attribute will centre the contents of the cell no matter what type of element they are.  text-align will only align inline elements to the centre.  For all other elements, they will only get centred if their margins on either side are equal - hence the need for margin auto

Comment: BTW if this isn't for an email template, then you shouldn't be using tables for layout purposes - tables should only be used for tabular data and as you are having nested tables, this does not look like it would be tabular data.  Also in html 5 the align attribute is obsolete so you should not use it

Comment: @Pete yes it is for an email template :D. Was wondering if someone would bring it up ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Semantically (and technically) speaking, `text-align` should only be used to [align inline level elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/text-align), of which a [`table`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table) is not.

The `align` property on a `table` doesn't refer to text but to

> **align**
>
> This enumerated attribute indicates how the table must be aligned inside the containing document.

---

As per the `table` docs above, `align` has been deprecated, and it is suggested that you do indeed use `margin:0 auto;` to "center" a `table` element

> Usage Note
>
> Do not use this attribute, as it has been deprecated. The `<table>` element should be styled using CSS.  Set `margin-left` and `margin-right` to auto or `margin` to 0 auto to achieve an effect that is similar to the align attribute.

Answer (score -2):

`text-align:center` only works for inline elements and obviously `table` is a table element.
set and try again

```
table table {
    display:inline;
}
```